# lc3 LDR instruction and the value stored

Tags: assembly, load, instructions, lc3

I can't figure out why `After instruction “LDR R3, R0, 2” is executed, the value stored in R3 is x370C.` what does 2 stands for in this instruction? It doesn't look like an immidiate value. I understand that R0 contains x370C at this point. Can someone please help? Many thanks!

```
.ORIG X3700
 LEA R0, A
 LDI R2, C 
 LDR R3, R0, 2 
 AND R1, R1, #0 
 IN
 ST R0, D 
 JSR  F 
 HALT
 F LD  R1, B
 ADD R1, R1, #1
 BRp F 
 RET

 A .FILL X1234
 B .FILL X370B
 C .FILL X370C
 D .BLKW 2
 E .STRINGZ "ABCD"
 G .FILL X1234
 .END
```

Comment: It seems a while since I played around, but let me answer this question, one second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is the offset of the base address that will be loaded.

I started to take some pictures to post here and make a good explanation but I found an interesting lecture video that will explain much better than words and will save a lot of time.

[LC3 Instructions - LD, LDR, LDI, LEA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDaPPXyYbH0)

The video is explaining the differences between the load instructions for the LC3, highlighting the differences between them.

In your example:

You have your data:

```
A .FILL X1234
B .FILL X370B
C .FILL X370C
```

Running your code:

```
LEA R0, A      -- R0 has the address of A
LDI R2, C      -- R2 has value of which address C has
LDR R3, R0, 2  -- R3 has the value of C 
               -- because R0 has the address of A + 2 positions = C
```

Comment: Thanks. It's funny because I actually have watched that video.. I understand that we are supposed to add the 'offset' to R0 and store that address to R3. The problem is that I don't know how to use the '2' in the instruction and add it to the R0.

Comment: Sorry, I really didnt understand, what you mean with `use the 2`?

Comment: I mean the second parameter in "LDR R3, R0, 2" is '2', which is supposed to be the offset, right? but there is no #before it, so it doesn't look like an immediate value. Then how can we add the offset to R0 and how come R3 is x370c?

Comment: Can you take a look at this? http://superuser.com/questions/904324/which-of-the-following-instructions-can-reference-a-memory-location-that-is-100