# Assembly Language - LD register into register

Tags: assembly, opcode, lc3

So I am a new assembly programmer,

And one concept I just cant seem to get my head around is how you would be able to

`LD R0, R1`

Where

`AND R0, R0, #0`

`AND R1, R1, #1`

I know you must load a memory address into a register with the `LD` opcode, but how would you be able to load a register containing decimal 1, into a register containing decimal 0?

I am trying to make a Fibonacci loop:

```
loop    ADD R2, R0, R1    ; F_i = F_0 + F_1
        LDI R0, R1        ; F_0 = F_1
        LDI R1, R2        ; F_1 = F_2
        AND R3, R3, #-1   ; decrements counter by 1
        BRp loop
```

Where I need to set load into `R0` and `R1` the newly computed Fibonacci sum `R2`

Comment: You can add zero to the source and store the result into the destination. Example: `ADD R2, R1, #0` will move `R1` into `R2`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using LC3 only with no updates (ie not LC3b). With this in mind, your use (and or understanding) of LD/LDI is incorrect. Have you tried compiling your code in LC3Edit? It'll spew out an error. Check out the responses of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868391/lc3-ldr-instruction-and-the-value-stored). From the LC3 instruction set PDF I found on the Net http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs252/Spring2007/handouts/lc3-1page.pdf: 
`LD DR, label ; Load PC-Relative
LDI DR, label ; Load Indirect`
One of the operands is not a register, instead it is a label, so you can not do 
`LD R0, R1`
 You will have to load, calculate, store for each loop.